# What can cause a user to be able to only see one row in a report? Browser issue?

Tags: zoho

I am new to Zoho Creator. We have a user that has emailed regarding viewing a report. When he pulls up the report, he can only see the first row of results and the up and down scroll arrows are stacked at the right of the row.

[Example](https://photos.app.goo.gl/E9koikvtA2BYiyTG8)

When I pull up the same report, it works as it should and I can see at least 30 results and can scroll down the list indefinitely.

[Example](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5KRMpkkdv2Kh1j717)

I have tried to recreate his issue by trying different browsers, resizing browser windows, changing my screen resolution, but cannot recreate his issue. Pretty sure it's not the Zoho app but more likely a setting or issue with the user's browser settings?

I need the user to be able to view more than just one row in his browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to go back and check user settings again. You may have set a criteria in the report based on the user login. It can be anything.

Or maybe, you've set something where the user can see only the records he/she has added.

Please click [here](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/views/restrict-visibility.html) to know more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you.